# Evaluation a this integral

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

If $f$ ia a continuously differentiable function on the unit circle and
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x-t)}{2\tan\frac{1}{2}t}dt
$$
evaluate
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{g(x+t)-g(x-t)}{2\tan\frac{1}{2}t}dt
$$

Comment: First site makes you feel ans is $f(x)$.

Comment: @exploringnet: Try plugging in $f(x)=\sin{x}$.  When I did, I got $-\sin{x}$ for the desired integral.

Comment: @RonGordon Haha, still observation was close , I hope answer comes out to be -f(x) . The symmetry in two relations forced me to think so.

Comment: It seems like trigonometric functions play nicely with the difference operator $f \mapsto f(x+t) - f(x-t) $. Maybe the answer is expressible in terms of the fourier expansion for $f$, assuming $f$ is $C^2$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$ for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the original transform $f \mapsto g$ by $g = \widetilde{f}$.

The point is that $f \mapsto \widetilde{f}$ acts diagonally in the Fourier basis for $C^1[-\pi, \pi]$; you can see this any one of a number of fancier ways but I'll stick to showing it computationally:

$$\widetilde{e^{i n (\cdot)}}(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{i n (x + t)} - e^{i n (x - t)}}{2 \tan \frac{t}{2}} dt = i e^{i n x} \left( \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \frac{\sin n t}{2 \tan \frac{t}{2}} dt \right)
$$

From here we can show that the parenthetical quantity on the far right side is equal to 1 for all $n \neq 0$, and 0 for $n = 0$. To show this directly is an exercise in complex analysis; simply expand the $\sin, \tan$'s into exponential form and then perform the substitution $z = e^{i t}$, integrating counterclockwise around the unit circle, picking up a residue at $z = 0$.

Now it should be clear that $\tilde{f} = i f$ when the zeroth fourier coefficient is zero, i.e. when $\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx = 0$. As $f \mapsto \tilde{f}$ acts as the zero operator on the subspace of constant functions, we now have
$$
\tilde{f}(x) = i \left(f(x) - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(y) dy \right)
$$
A second application of $\mapsto$ gives $- \left(f(x) - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(y) dy \right)$.